# Liquibase A Good Replacement for Krasimir Method of Database Syncing?

Tags: database, database-migrations

Like everyone, a major headache for us has been keeping databases between development and production servers in sync. We had implemented Krasimir's method to great success.

http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Deploying-ExpressionEngine-based-site

But after upgrading EE to 2.8.x it stopped working. We haven't really had time to troubleshoot and I don't even know how popular this solution was but we haven't had any luck Googling quick answers.

I ran across Liquibase earlier today and it seems like a more generalized implementation of the same idea.

Anyone used Liquibase with EE? Any reason to think it might not be a good solution? Alternatively, anyone had luck fixing Krasimir's method?

Thanks.